# Javascript profiling on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, profiling

I am looking for tools that allow to perform profiling of websites on mobile devices similar to what Firebug and Chrome dev tools allow to do.

I have used Weinre quite extensive. While it is an awesome tool to use with real devices, it does not provide facilities for run-time profiling.

Has anyone heard or used any tools that allow to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a great list of mobile performance testing tools from Steve Sauders (the guy that wrote the book "High Performance Web Sites"):

- [Mobile Perf bookmarklet](http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/mobileperfbkm.php) - An uber bookmarklet with links to multiple other bookmarklets useful for mobile (mine)
- [Jdrop](http://jdrop.org/) - JSON in the cloud for gathering data on mobile devices (mine)
- [Mobitest](http://blaze.io/mobile/) - Connects WebPagetest.org to Android and iPhone devices (Blaze.io)
- [pcapperf](http://pcapperf.appspot.com/) - Get HTTP waterfall charts from your mobile device connected to a wifi hotspot, blog post (open source)
- [WebWait](http://webwait.com/) - The only way I can think of to measure page load times on real devices over 3G - load URL in an iframe (Michael Mahemoff)
- [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) - Web Inspector Remote, very cool way to debug your mobile device remotely (Patrick Mueller)
- [Reflow Timer](http://www.browserscope.org/reflow/about) - Bookmarklet to measure reflow time (Lindsey Simon, open source)
- [Favelet Suite](http://slayeroffice.com/?c=/content/tools/suite.html) - An uber bookmarklet, tons of features! (slayeroffice)

*Source: http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/*

**UPDATE:**

You can use Chrome Devtools with an Android device and you can use Safari Devtools on a Mac with an iOS device.

Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Safari: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/

You connect via USB

Answer (score 1):

You can profile/debug/inspect Chrome-on-Android using the desktop Chrome developer tools interface:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

It'll require Chrome, an Android device able to run the Chrome app, and a USB cable.

Its a bit annoying to setup, because you have to install and use the ADB console command, but once its working, you'll have the full chrome developer tools interface available for debugging mobile.

Additionally, Google appears to be supporting this feature for new dev-tool Crhome extensions like PageSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS debugging on Mac, you can use desktop Safari:

- connect your device with a USB cable
- start the app on the device
- launch Safari on your computer
- go to Develop -> **device_name** -> file_name.html

*(if the `Develop` menu is not available for you, then go to `Edit` menu > `Preferences...` > `Advanced` tab and check `Show Develop menu in menu bar` checkbox)*

It launches standard Safari web inspector, which is pretty similar to Chrome Developer Tools, although somewhat limited compared to it.