# Profile javascript for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, profiling

I have an intensive javascript page that is running on a mobile device.  Some of the animations are a little laggy.  I wanted to see where the bottle necks were.  Is there a tool that will allow me to profile the javascript to see where can be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Android device, you can use the Chrome Android app along with Chrome on your desktop to debug/profile/inspect by USB:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

Its a bit annoying to setup, because you have to install and use the ADB console command, but once its working, you won't go back.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to what you're asking:

[Javascript profiling on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005346/javascript-profiling-on-mobile-devices)

It's a nice list of profilers that you can use to test your js performance.